# Drupal 7: retrieving data from fields of custom content type for a feature/module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Thanks in advance for your help! I have a custom content type called "Gear Post" for my Drupal project that allows me to review bicycle gear. Gear Post has a field called "weight" for the weight of the item. I am trying to write my own module aka feature that allows the user to calculate the weight of all the gear items stored as Gear Posts on the site. I'm struggling to gain access to the weight property of the gear post.

This is what I have so far:
(.module file)

```
<?php
 function get_content_fields_array() {
 $list = node_type_get_names(); //just for info
 echo $list['gear_post']; //this correctly gets 'Gear Post'
 $field_list = field_info_instances('node', 'gear_post');

 $allFieldKeys = array_keys($field_list);
 echo ($allFieldKeys[4]); //'field_weight'
```

???

I tried using array_keys because I find associative arrays hard to read when I output them via var_dump.

What I want to be able to do is have an array of all of the Weights so I can iterate through them and show them, and then use them for my math.  But I don't know how to gain access to the actual value of the weight field for each Gear Post.

thank you so much - I am new to learning Drupal (day 2..)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying and poking about, I was able to solve this myself. Pretty exciting. Not sure if this is best practice, but it works. [This](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) this was helpful in figuring it out!

```
function getWeights() {
 $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
 $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'gear_post')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
  $result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
  $weights = array();

   foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $fields = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_weight'); 
      array_push ($weights, $fields[0]['#markup']);
     }
 }
 return $weights;
}
```

Comment: Also [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77798/how-to-iterate-over-all-the-nodes-from-a-content-type) was very helpful.